# jQuery live to on, with $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm updating my scripts so those are working in jQuery 1.9+

`live` is removed and I have to convert it to the `on` syntax. [There are some examples on the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/). The documentation gives:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // jQuery 1.7
```

So
`$("a").live("click", handler)` schould be converted to `$(document).on("click","a", handler)` and so on.

But how do I convert when I have no `selector`? In my case this is inside a plugin.

```
$(this).live("click", handler)
```

This is not working:

```
$(document).on("click",$(this), handler)
```

--edit

I need delegation, so `bind` is not the solution. This is used inside a plugin, where I the code is

`elem.live("click", handler)`, where `elem` is sometimes a selector, and sometimes `$(this)`. I have no control on that.

Comment: It's pointless anyway. Both `.live()` and `.on()` are meant for elements **created on the fly**, after the event is attached. In case of `$(this)` it's an existing element already so just use `.click()` or `.bind(click, ...)`.

Comment: selector for target of delegated event can only be a string as specified in DOC

Comment: This is not a pointless post IMO, but i cannot see the purpose of using delegation here as when you use `this`, you are refering a/some specific element(s) so why not bound event directly to it without using delegation. Could you provide a concrete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by examining the source code of the [jQuery migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)

It was looking for the [.context property](http://api.jquery.com/context/). The answer to the question is

```
$(document).on("click", $(this.context), handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
$(this).on("click", handler);
```

or

```
$(this).click(handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

The .on method can be used as below:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    // handle the click
});
```

Also, in the code you had the `$(this)` would be the document itself rather than what you intended the click to bind to.